# html5 video with jquery and inview - how to point to the right video element?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, inview

I use the jquery inview plugin top automatically play videos when in view. Since I cannot use IDs for the video I use html5 `<video>` as selector and all videos are always starting to play. How can I point the play/pause trigger only to the one element that is currently triggering the event and ignore all the others?

```
$('.video-autoplay').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    $('video').trigger('play');
  } else {
    $('video').trigger('pause');
  }
});
```

many thanks,
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `this`. For more information, see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/1350913)

```js
$('.video-autoplay').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    $(this).trigger('play');
  } else {
    $(this).trigger('pause');
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, that brought me to the right idea. :-) "This" works with a small edit. The first selector $('.video-autoplay') needs to contain the video element like $('.video-autoplay video') since the video element needs to be triggered.